# is there a better way to merge array of objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

Basically, I want to format the results I am querying from the database to a new object using **Javascript** or any of its **npm modules**.

I have the following array of objects from the database:

```
[
  {
    "invoice_id": 1,
    "item_id": 23,
    "client_id": 2,
    "price": 3000.00,
    "qty": 4
  },
  {
    "invoice_id": 1,
    "item_id": 45,
    "client_id": 2,
    "price": 8000.00,
    "qty": 1
  },
  {
    "invoice_id": 1,
    "item_id": 56,
    "client_id": 2,
    "price": 10000.00,
    "qty": 1
  },
],
```

I want to merge the above objects in the following format:

```
[
  {
    "invoice": {
      "invoice_id": 1,
      "items": [
        {
          "item_id": 23,
          "price": 3000.00,
          "qty": 4
        },
        {
          "item_id": 45,
          "price": 8000.00,
          "qty": 1
        },
        {
          "item_id": 56,
          "price": 10000.00,
          "qty": 1
        }
      ],
    },
    "client": {
      "client_id": 2,
    }
  }
]
```

Any recommendation of how I can do perform the above result?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Can you share what output you are expecting?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()` or you can loop through the array item in any other way.

Comment: By the way, could you confirm that what you want as output is an array of invoices and not a single invoice object, please?

Comment: To know if there is a *better way*, we would first need to know your *current way*

Comment: @mplungjan Well noted, thanks for your recommendations!

Answer (score 1):

My approach

I use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for the incoming data array, to walk over every item in the array and return a new array.
In my reduce function I check, if there is an item with the current `invoice_id` and `client_id`. If not, I will create it
Then I push a new item with the `item_id`, `qty` and `price`

```js
{
  "use strict";
  
  const data = [
  {
    "invoice_id": 1,
    "item_id": 23,
    "client_id": 2,
    "price": 3000.00,
    "qty": 4
  },
  {
    "invoice_id": 1,
    "item_id": 45,
    "client_id": 2,
    "price": 8000.00,
    "qty": 1
  },
  {
    "invoice_id": 1,
    "item_id": 56,
    "client_id": 2,
    "price": 10000.00,
    "qty": 1
  },
]
  const parsedData = data.reduce((carry, item) => {
    let temp = carry.find(e => e.invoice?.invoice_id == item.invoice_id && e.client?.client_id == item.client_id);
    if (temp === undefined) {
      temp = carry[carry.push({}) - 1]
      temp.invoice = {invoice_id: item.invoice_id, items: []}
      temp.client = {client_id: item.client_id}
    }
    temp.invoice.items.push({item_id: item.item_id, price: item.price, qty: item.qty})
    return carry
  }, [])
  
  console.log(parsedData)
}
```